# How to find the error of G++ optimize C++ code?

Tags: c++, linux

Today, I encounter a strange problem. My c++ code can work under debug mode. 
 using g++ -g to compile the code. However, when I use g++ -O to optimize the code. It will stuck somewhere. It seems there is dead looping. Does anybody know how to find this kind of error? When I debug the code with DDD debuger, it works fine. Thanks!

The part of code (I find the stuck came from this part) is pasted below:

```
void Solver::reduceRoutes()
{
    int V=pinst->get_V();   //get the given number of vehicles
    if(int(curSol_.size())<=V)    // return when solution has no extra routes 
        return;

    int routeNum1,routeNum2;   // the two routes modified

    listSize=int(0.2*pinst->get_N());

    short TheNode,anode;          // the second node
    float totalInc;               //the obj increase of a candidate position
    Route::iterator it;
    vector<short> candidateList;
    vector<short> validCandidateList;  //nodes can be moved to
    vector<float> totalImpList;
    int solSize=int(curSol_.size());

    while(solSize>V)
    {
        //  cout <<"debug6.0 ";
        routeNum1=psol->findRouteWithMinC(curSol_);
        cout <<" debug6.1 "<<curSol_.size()<<" "<<routeNum1;
        while(curSol_[routeNum1].size()>2)
        {
            it=curSol_[routeNum1].begin();
            it++;
            TheNode=*it;
            candidateList=pinst->get_PNL(TheNode,listSize);

            // evaluate the effect of moving the node to each possible position

            for(unsigned int i=1;i<candidateList.size();i++)      //the first node is itself
            {
                anode=candidateList[i];

                routeNum2=RouteNumList[anode];  //find the route of second node
                if(routeNum2!=routeNum1)         //inter route move
                {  
                    totalInc=evaluateAreduceRouteMove(curSol_,routeNum1,routeNum2,TheNode,anode);
                    totalImpList.push_back(totalInc);
                    validCandidateList.push_back(anode);
                }
            }

            //find the best position to insert the
            int ii=(min_element(totalImpList.begin(),totalImpList.end())-totalImpList.begin());
            anode=validCandidateList[ii];

            it=find(curSol_[routeNum1].begin(),curSol_[routeNum1].end(),TheNode);
            curSol_[routeNum1].erase(it);       //remove from route1

            routeNum2=RouteNumList[anode];
            it=find(curSol_[routeNum2].begin(),curSol_[routeNum2].end(),anode);
            ++it;
            curSol_[routeNum2].insert(it,TheNode);  //insert to the second route
            RouteNumList[TheNode]=routeNum2;        //update route number
            //improve the modified routes

            psol->doTwoOpt(curSol_[routeNum2]);
            totalImpList.clear();
            validCandidateList.clear();
        }

        //update route number list
        for(unsigned int i=routeNum1+1;i<curSol_.size();i++)
        {
            for(it=curSol_[i].begin();it!=curSol_[i].end();it++)
                RouteNumList[*it]-=1;

        }

        RouteNumList[0]=0;
        // eliminate the empty route
        curSol_.erase(curSol_.begin()+routeNum1);
        solSize=curSol_.size();
        cout <<" debug6.3 "<<solSize<< " \n";

    }

    return;
}
```

---

Thanks you for answering my questions. Now my code works without optimizing. I just wonder what the optimizer does thus the code does work. If the optimize mode does not improve the speed much, then it is ok not using it. Can anyone comment on the power of optimize mode?
Thanks again.

Comment: Please indent all your code by four spaces, it will put it in a code block.

Comment: Tips to start with: Split up in differnt functions for readability. Initialize all variables when you declare them. Don't reuse the same variable for multiple purposes. Run with a checked STL version to ensure you dont make errors with iterators pointing to modified containers (common problem)

Comment: If it doesn't work in optimized mode almost certainly there's a bug in your code that will eventually cause the non-optimized version to fail as well.

Comment: @Greg: Agreed. It doesn't make sense to accept just any junk as the answer when it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is it that at the beginning of the loop you typecasted the solSize to int `int solSize=int(curSol_.size());` but didn't do that in the while loop `solSize=curSol_.size();`. You might want to investigate the values in the debug and the optimized version.

Also, there seem to be places in the code where there are floats / doubles being compared with (may be) integers. May be that is the cause of the infinite loop.

Comment: There are rules for comparing floating-point types to integer types.  The danger here is that the floating-point values may not be precise, so the comparison (particularly any equality comparison) may be slightly off.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're hitting a compiler bug (and I've hit fewer than one per decade), the issue is that you have code that doesn't have fully defined behavior, and it's being compiled one way in debug mode and another way when optimizing.  People who write optimizers do not generally take responsibility for undefined or unspecified behavior; if the code is wrong, so's the output.

Have you tried enabling all possible warnings?  Some of them might give you some insight as to what is wrong.  Taking a quick look over the code you've included doesn't suggest anything to me.

It's also possible that you have undefined behavior elsewhere in your program, most likely heap corruption.  That's always fun to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

How do you know this is where you are hanging?  Was it from printf/cout debugging?  If so, you're on the right track.  That can be a powerful tool in situations like these.

I agree with Gangadhar, check your types.  If you specify other optimization levels, does it still hang?  What if you turn off optimization and don't include debug symbols (no -O or -g options)?

Comment: yes, I added cout to a few positions and found the code stopped here.

It did not hang without -O. In fact, I have tested with an instance, when the CurSol.size() = 197, it stucked. Now I just have no clue how to find where it stucked.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use a couple calls to `pstack` to find out where your program is when it's looping. If that isn't available or doesn't yield satisfactory results, your best bet is `cout`s...a LOT of `cout`s, within every point of the function to narrow down exactly where it's hung. Without that information we're just guessing blind. Compile with `-Wall` and make sure there aren't any warnings.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is make sure all your code compiles clean.
Most of these types of errors result in you using (unwittingly) some undefined behavior or accidentally doing something silly. The compiler will warn you about most of these situations, so you can use this to your advantage.

Add the following:

> -ansi -pedantic -W -Wall -Werror

That will force you to fix all the simple problems.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the error. The problem derived from the comparison of float type variables. Due to the precision, the comparison caused infinite looping. Thanks you guys.
you are really helpful.